# Configure Manifest To Suppress Webkitdirectory Warning in Chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, google-chrome-extension, webkit

When uploading files using the `webkitdirectory` option in an HTML `<input>` tag, chrome and other browsers warn a user of how many files they will be uploading. I am developing a chrome extension, and I was wondering if there is any permission that can be added to my extension's manifest that will suppress this warning, as the entire extension is based around this functionality and it gets annoying granting permission again and again to my own extension.

Comment: Extensions can't influence that. Or rather the workaround would be terrifyingly complex: you can write an external utility that draws a transparent rectangle over the input element (only when the tab is activated) and intercepts the drag'n'drop operation, reads the files, and sends the contents via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm this is what I feared.  I was hoping for a permission that approved this by default but it looks like I’m bamboozled for now...